# Multiple proxy_pass locations with php

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I would like to have two proxy_pass locations and a generic php-fpm location as well so that any .php request is forwarded to fpm-php but any request to either /el/... or /gl/... go to those locations. This is what I have so far:

```
server {
listen *:443 ssl;    

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

client_max_body_size 108M;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

root /var/www/public;
index index.php;

if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
}

location /es/ {
    proxy_pass http://<my-domain>:8200/;
}

location /gl/ {
    proxy_pass http://<my-domain>:3000/;
}

location / {

   location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass <my-domain>:9000;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/php_errors.log";
       fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
       fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
       include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
}
```

This configuration fails on all three counts. However removing all the php location and the 'if' statement works for the /es/ and /gl/ locations, so I guess that i am not doing the php bit correctly. What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last; }
```

as:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

and move it into the `location /` block, to avoid nasty conflicts with global `if` and `rewrite` statements.

Use the `^~` modifier on the prefix locations that take precedence over regular expression locations. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
root /var/www/public;
index index.php;

location ^~ /es/ {
    proxy_pass http://<my-domain>:8200/;
}

location ^~ /gl/ {
    proxy_pass http://<my-domain>:3000/;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_pass <my-domain>:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/php_errors.log";
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
}
```

Place your `fastcgi_param` statements after `include fastcgi_params;` to avoid them being silently overridden by the included file.